# Why is one question acceptable and another is not?

Tags: discussion, review-audits

Recently I had flagged an answer as not an answer, this was declined as "declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it"

[restore all mysql database from a --all-database sql.gz file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23180963/restore-all-mysql-database-from-a-all-database-sql-gz-file/58458893#58458893)

As such while going through the reviews I found myself with this: https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/24361448

However, in this instance, this is considered not an answer even though, in my opinion, it provided additional information which the first didn't. Correct or not it was an "answer" if the one provided in the declined flag was indeed an answer.

To help my own understanding could I ask why one is acceptable and the other isn't?

Comment: The main difference is that the first answer has been reviewed by a mod and the second one was deleted by community members. Stack Overflow has an incredible lenient definition for what an answer is and what isn't. Mods need to adhere to that rule, but community members don't, so they can delete bad posts when there are enough members to support it. Your first answer was also "recommended for deletion" by a community member before a mod declined the flag.

Comment: I was unaware of that so thank you for that information. My review really came based on the flag being declined but if that's the case I'll take the temp ban from reviews.

Comment: I skip answers as well when I do reviews (which I do very rarely these days), because I should say "looks ok" (due to the 'rules' on SO), but I won't put my name under such posts and call them ok.

Comment: @tom for good reasons. https://xkcd.com/979/ That oneliner, although not explained at all, might somewhen lead someone into the right direction ...

Comment: @JonasWilms I agree, I also search for gz packed scripts and then ignore all other answers explaining that and instead work with the answer which doesn't give a damn about packed scripts.

Comment: @tom yeah well but the moderator cannot judge the quality of the answer cause that would need technical expertise in every field. I'd downvote and move on.

Comment: @JonasWilms That's what I tried to explain with my first comment. They are not required to have expertise on  the subject matter, but also don't need to skip that review, because the rules for such answers are clear and in favor for them. Community members can have technical expertise, hence different outcome of "equal" answers. So I agree with you here.

Comment: @tom might write that up as an answer ...

Comment: @JonasWilms You won't believe how lazy I am. But I will support your answer if you want write one :).